# combine two different classifier result in scikit-learn python

Tags: python, time-series, classification, scikit-learn, prediction

I got data sets like below:-

```
patient id-1
```

**`Heart rate pattern-82 82 87 87 89 90 89 89 89 89`**

```
Blood pressure-110 71

Body temperature-37.2

SPO2-94

Sex-0

Age-8

Hereditary-1

Smoking-0

Alcohol Intake-0

Physical Activity-1

Diabetes-0

Blood Cholesterol-0

Obesity BMI-17.5

Status-0
```

*(1=bad(true), 0=good(false))*

**For Heart rate pattern**

```
>>>est = AdaBoostClassifier()
>>>est.fit(X_train,y_train)
>>>predictions = est.predict(X_test)
>>>r2_score(y_test,predictions)
0.46999999999999997
```

**For rest of the data**

```
>>>est = RandomForestClassifier(verbose=2)
>>>est.fit(X_train,y_train)
>>>predictions = est.predict(X_test)
>>>r2_score(y_test,predictions)
0.9
```

i only had 264 of test data for training and testing. by mining only the **heart rate patterns** using AdaBoostClassifier() in sklearn i gain 0.46999999999999997 of accuracy. and for the rest of the data set separately i gain 0.9 accuracy using RandomForestClassifier(verbose=2).

now i need to combine these two results in to single prediction result. since heart rate is a time series i cant combine these two result straight away. What is the best way connect these two results?

Comment: r2_score is a regression score, not a classification score. To evaluate classification, use f1_score, accuracy_score (only suitable for balanced classes) or roc_auc_score (only for binary classification).

Comment: @ogrisel what is the difference between r2 and f1_score ? what is the most accurate and correct in above scenario? should i bother about both of them or only one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To combine the classification of two classifiers that output class assignment probabilities (via the `predict_proba` method) you can average (possibly with some weights) the probabilies and take the `argmax` over the average predicted class probabilities for the final prediction.

Note: the order of othe columns of the `predict_proba` output depends on the `classes_` attribute of the classifier.

Comment: will you post a sample code to do that? *i just need more clarifications, Im kind a new to scikit learn

Comment: Thank you for this protip.  This is what I did for nested cross validation while doing an exhaustive subset on possible terms.

Answer (score 7):

You can also automatically do this using sklearn VotingClassifier to combine different Machine Learning clasiffiers and predict the "most voted" output from all your set of classifiers.

In your example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

est_AB = AdaBoostClassifier()
score_AB=est_AB.fit(X_train,y_train).score(X_test,y_test)

est_RF = RandomForestClassifier()
score_RF=est_RF.fit(X_train,y_train).score(X_test,y_test)

est_Ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('AB', est_AB), ('RF', est_RF)],
                        voting='soft',
                        weights=[1, 1])

score_Ensemble=est_Ensemble.fit(X_train,y_train).score(X_test,y_test)
```

voting='soft' predicts the labels as the ones with the maximum probabilities after suming all models predictions. voting='hard' predicts the labels following majority vote rule, i.e. the mode of the models predictions.

See more here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#voting-classifier
and here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html

Comment: while the document you linked could answer to the question it's always better to include the relevant code in the answer and give the link as reference

Comment: DaFois - I edited and added the corresponding implemention